# Can't update value of IntegerField of Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    how_many_new_notifications = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

In views.py function which is 100% called and `whom` is present

```
whom.profile.how_many_new_notifications += 1
whom.save()
```

Whatever, `how_many_new_notifications` is still equal zero and not incremented , despite everything else is correct

Also tried something like this:

```
  if  whom.profile.how_many_new_notifications  ==  None:
            whom.profile.how_many_new_notifications = 1
  else:
            varible_number_of_notifications = int(  whom.profile.how_many_new_notifications)
            whom.profile.how_many_new_notifications = varible_number_of_notifications  + 1
```

Get no errors in log, is there any reason why this code wouldn't work, or should I search for issues in other places?

Comment: Can you try to change `whom.save()` to `whom.profile.save()`.

Comment: And `how_much_notifications` to `how_many_notifications`, not to fix the bug but :-)

Comment: @vanadium23 didn't help

Comment: @RemcoGerlich edited :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User.profile` is a property that gets a new copy of the profile each time it is used.

So when you do

```
user.profile.how_many_notifications += 1
user.profile.save()
```

Each line uses its own copy of the profile, the two Python objects are unrelated.

So you need to do

```
profile = user.profile
profile.how_many_notifications += 1
profile.save()
```

But using a profile property like that is a bit odd -- you have a OneToOneField, and a related property is already automatically defined as the lower case name of your class. So

```
user.userprofile.how_many_new_notifications += 1
user.userprofile.save()
```

Should also work. If you want to change the name `userprofile`, use `related_name`:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

And then it works with `user.profile`.

Comment: Or, not override the behaviour of the reverse lookup in the first place...

Comment: He doesn't override it I believe, the reverse is .user_profile I think? I'll add a bit.